# Javascript wrapping chained functions in a single function

Tags: javascript, chaining, intern

I am using `intern` for some javascript functional tests, and would like to start abstracting my test code out a little to make it a bit more reusable.  Im not sure if this is even possible, but I am trying to achieve the following -

My original code has the following format -

```
this.remote.get(URL).setFindTimeout(5000).end()
.findByXpath(xpath).click().type('XXX').end().
.findByXpath(xpath).click().type('YYY').end()
.findByCSSSelector(css).click().doSelectBoxStuff().end() //and so on...
```

Where each line could possibly be the input of a different *type* of input field.  I am trying to abstract out the functionality, when entering into these different input types, into their own functions, like this -

```
this.remote.get(URL).setFindTimeout(5000).end()
    .enterTextBox('XXX')
    .enterTextBox('YYY')
    .enterSelectBox('ZZZ')

function enterTextBox(val){
    //execute  .findByXpath(xpath).click().type(val).end()
}

function enterSelectBox(val){
    //execute  .findByCSSSelector(css).click().doSelectBoxStuff().end()
}
```

Is something like this possible?  If so, what would call `.findByXPath(xpath)...` etc on within my two new functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can. Just pass functions as arguments to functions. You can define methods for an object by changing its prototype. So to achieve the behavior you want, you'd write this:

```
// Ideally, replace this.remote.get(URL) with a base instance of the object
this.remote.get(URL).prototype.enterTextBox = function() {
    return this.findByXpath(xpath).click().type(val).end()
}

this.remote.get(URL).setFindTimeout(5000).end()
    .enterTextBox('XXX')
```

etc. The key thing is to return the obj so it can be chained.

Comment: thanks, what would `obj` be in this case that would be getting passed into `enterTextBox`?

Comment: I re-read your question and updated my answer. You'd want to modify that intern object's prototype, to add `enterTextBox` as a method.

Comment: tried a few different things, but always getting `cannot read property findByXPath of undefined`

Comment: Although I wasnt able to get the solution exactly working with what you have put, it did force me to read up on trying to extend the intern prototype. Which led me to...http://albertogasparin.it/articles/2015/04/extend-intern-leadfoot-commands/ Which is exactly what I needed! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform chaining then your function must return the "Object" on which you are performing operations.